# O que é um chrome?

Tags: terminologia

Note que chrome está em minúsculo, não estou falando do navegador. O que significa o termo chrome na programação? Quando é apropriado usá-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome é o nome que se dá para os elementos que formam a janela da aplicação. Estamos falando só da "borda" dela, não o miolo da janela. É o que circunda o conteúdo. O termo completo seria *user interface chrome* para ficar menos ambíguo do que se se trata.

Pode incluir o menu, barra de rolagem, botões de navegação e comandos, título, caixa de comunicação com o conteúdo. Ele é o oposto do conteúdo, o que não são os dados do usuário. É uma maneira de dar um nome genérico para os vários elementos de controle da aplicação que roda que não é o foco principal.

Não precisa ser em uma janela do sistema operacional, pode ser em uma página de internet. É possível ter um chrome do navegador (não confundir com o Chrome) e pode ter o chrome da página que está acessando, por exemplo o rodapé faz parte do chrome da página.

Por exemplo, a barra de ferramentas, geralmente embaixo da tela, com o botão iniciar e outros elementos ali é o chrome do Windows.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).